# Auto complete in Visual Studio Code not working For Bootstrap 4?

Tags: autocomplete, visual-studio-code, bootstrap-4, intellisense

I have a problem with auto complete for Bootstrap classes in Visual Studio Code.

every solution in google show way with tap every times ctrl+space to show auto completing for bootstrap, but this is really no comfortable always tap this shortcut every time.

For example in Sublime text everything works really cool with bootstrap, but VS code is more comfortable for me.
Can anyone help with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

VS Code doesn't natively support Bootstrap classes.
Most probably you've seen usage of VS extensions.
[Here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=thekalinga.bootstrap4-vscode) is an example of such good extension.
And [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=bootstrap&target=VSCode&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance) are much more from the store just in case you need.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I know about theses extensions. Oh, really bad about natively support, or extensions like in sublime (